# Fullscreen activity wizard activity. How do I stop actionbar from showing when I interact with device?

Tags: android, android-actionbar

When I create an activity using the [fullscreen activity wizard](http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/templates.html#full-screen-activity) it creatre a fullscreen activity but whenever I click anywhere on the screen the actionbar shows for a few seconds. How can I stop it from doing so?

**Full code of FullScreenActivity.java**

```
/**
 * An example full-screen activity that shows and hides the system UI (i.e.
 * status bar and navigation/system bar) with user interaction.
 * 
 * @see SystemUiHider
 */
public class FullscreenActivity extends Activity {
    /**
     * Whether or not the system UI should be auto-hidden after
     * {@link #AUTO_HIDE_DELAY_MILLIS} milliseconds.
     */
    private static final boolean AUTO_HIDE = true;

    /**
     * If {@link #AUTO_HIDE} is set, the number of milliseconds to wait after
     * user interaction before hiding the system UI.
     */
    private static final int AUTO_HIDE_DELAY_MILLIS = 3000;

    /**
     * If set, will toggle the system UI visibility upon interaction. Otherwise,
     * will show the system UI visibility upon interaction.
     */
    private static final boolean TOGGLE_ON_CLICK = true;

    /**
     * The flags to pass to {@link SystemUiHider#getInstance}.
     */
    private static final int HIDER_FLAGS = SystemUiHider.FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION;

    /**
     * The instance of the {@link SystemUiHider} for this activity.
     */
    private SystemUiHider mSystemUiHider;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_fullscreen);

        final View controlsView = findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_content_controls);
        final View contentView = findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_content);

        // Set up an instance of SystemUiHider to control the system UI for
        // this activity.
        mSystemUiHider = SystemUiHider.getInstance(this, contentView,
                HIDER_FLAGS);
        mSystemUiHider.setup();
        mSystemUiHider
                .setOnVisibilityChangeListener(new SystemUiHider.OnVisibilityChangeListener() {
                    // Cached values.
                    int mControlsHeight;
                    int mShortAnimTime;

                    @Override
                    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2)
                    public void onVisibilityChange(boolean visible) {
                        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2) {
                            // If the ViewPropertyAnimator API is available
                            // (Honeycomb MR2 and later), use it to animate the
                            // in-layout UI controls at the bottom of the
                            // screen.
                            if (mControlsHeight == 0) {
                                mControlsHeight = controlsView.getHeight();
                            }
                            if (mShortAnimTime == 0) {
                                mShortAnimTime = getResources().getInteger(
                                        android.R.integer.config_shortAnimTime);
                            }
                            controlsView
                                    .animate()
                                    .translationY(visible ? 0 : mControlsHeight)
                                    .setDuration(mShortAnimTime);
                        } else {
                            // If the ViewPropertyAnimator APIs aren't
                            // available, simply show or hide the in-layout UI
                            // controls.
                            controlsView.setVisibility(visible ? View.VISIBLE
                                    : View.GONE);
                        }

                        if (visible && AUTO_HIDE) {
                            // Schedule a hide().
                            delayedHide(AUTO_HIDE_DELAY_MILLIS);
                        }
                    }
                });

        // Set up the user interaction to manually show or hide the system UI.
        contentView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (TOGGLE_ON_CLICK) {
                    mSystemUiHider.toggle();
                } else {
                    mSystemUiHider.show();
                }
            }
        });

        // Upon interacting with UI controls, delay any scheduled hide()
        // operations to prevent the jarring behavior of controls going away
        // while interacting with the UI.
        findViewById(R.id.dummy_button).setOnTouchListener(
                mDelayHideTouchListener);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Trigger the initial hide() shortly after the activity has been
        // created, to briefly hint to the user that UI controls
        // are available.
        delayedHide(100);
    }

    /**
     * Touch listener to use for in-layout UI controls to delay hiding the
     * system UI. This is to prevent the jarring behavior of controls going away
     * while interacting with activity UI.
     */
    View.OnTouchListener mDelayHideTouchListener = new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            if (AUTO_HIDE) {
                delayedHide(AUTO_HIDE_DELAY_MILLIS);
            }
            return false;
        }
    };

    Handler mHideHandler = new Handler();
    Runnable mHideRunnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mSystemUiHider.hide();
        }
    };

    /**
     * Schedules a call to hide() in [delay] milliseconds, canceling any
     * previously scheduled calls.
     */
    private void delayedHide(int delayMillis) {
        mHideHandler.removeCallbacks(mHideRunnable);
        mHideHandler.postDelayed(mHideRunnable, delayMillis);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 12):

if i understand correctly, you just want to hide the action bar?

if yes, Change this line (changing the flag_hide_navigation to 0).

```
private static final int HIDER_FLAGS = 0;// SystemUiHider.FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION;
```

and add this to the onCreate call:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);   //new
    getActionBar().hide();                                   //new
    getWindow().setFlags(
         WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_fullscreen);
```

afterwards, if you want to show the action bar, just call from anywhere in the activity :

```
getActionBar().show();
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll still have to find out how to integrate this with the animation, but this does prevent the action bar from reappearing upon interaction as was needed.

Answer (score 2):

I Tried The Same By Putting 0 in place of 3000

```
private static final int AUTO_HIDE_DELAY_MILLIS = 3000;
```

But its becoming too laggy...
So,The trick u to make changes in `androidmanifest.xml`
add

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
```

to `AndroidManifest.xml` underApplication

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me. Although the navigator isn't removed completely it doesn't allow much time for the user to interact, plus the button icons are small dots. Also this cuts down on the amount of code needed all over the place to make a screen fullscreen.

```
SystemUiHider hider = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //go full screen with no title
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS); //show progress on loadup
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); //hide the title bar
    this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN); //go fullscreen

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //hide the navigation controls
    final RelativeLayout mainLayout = (RelativeLayout)this.findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);
    hider = SystemUiHider.getInstance(this, mainLayout, SystemUiHider.FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION);
    hider.setup();
    hider.setOnVisibilityChangeListener(new SystemUiHider.OnVisibilityChangeListener() {
        @Override
        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2)
        public void onVisibilityChange(boolean visible) {
            if (visible) {
                //will make navigator into small dots
                hider.hide(); 

                //must use delayed to force navigator to disappear completely
                final Handler mHideHandler = new Handler();
                final Runnable mHideRunnable = new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        hider.hide();
                    }
                };
                mHideHandler.removeCallbacks(mHideRunnable);
                mHideHandler.postDelayed(mHideRunnable, 1000); //min 1 sec to work
            }
        }
    });
    hider.hide();

    //do the rest of your onCreate stuff here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I took a deep look into the code and started the activity on an Android 4.2 device without physical navigation buttons. The default configuration is as fullscreen as possible. It hides **status bar**, **action bar** and **navigation bar**. So how would the user be supposed to get out of your activity if not with a click anywhere on the screen? Anything else would be very restricting and bad usability. I think this is the reason why this behavior can not be manipulated.

What you can do instead, is change the `SystemUiHider` so that it hides the status bar and the action bar, but **not** the navigation bar. It instead dimmes the navigation bar to three pale dots, see the screenshot below.

[image: dimmed navigation bar]

There must be a better way to achieve this, but the following works. Comment these lines in the end of the `SystemUiHiderHoneycomb()` constructor:

```
if ((mFlags & FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION) != 0) {
    // If the client requested hiding navigation, add relevant flags.
    mShowFlags |= View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION;
    mHideFlags |= View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION;
    mTestFlags = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION;
}
```

The activity then stays fullscreen on user interaction and you can `toggle()` it at a particular event. Of course, you would still have to do the change from my original answer to disable the click behavior.

---

**Original answer:**

I guess you have to comment this part:

```
// Set up the user interaction to manually show or hide the system UI.
contentView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (TOGGLE_ON_CLICK) {
            mSystemUiHider.toggle();
        } else {
            mSystemUiHider.show();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: This doesn't work, the system automatically resets the action bar upon interaction. The code above only allows you to hide the UI when its visible, so the mSystemUiHider.show(); part is pretty much redundant. I'm also looking for a way to override this behavior.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'll give this a try although I'm still looking for a solution that includes the navigation bar. If you've used the Kindle app, you'll understand why this would be useful. In this app, you can show the navigation by clicking on the center of the screen, but flicking a page or clicking at the left or right of the screen doesn't have this effect. Reappearing the navigation bar when flicking a page is not only annoying, it also requires you to flick twice, since the first click is consumed by the action that triggers this effect. It must be possible since Kindle does it.

Comment: @JayPea Kindle runs a modified version of Android with changes to core libraries so I wouldn't point at them for proof. Having said that, it probably *is* possible.

Comment: @yarian Yes but I mean the Kindle android app, not the device. Also, there's an app called Aldiko which has this feature as well.

Answer (score 1):

In api19 we can use:

```
getWindow().getDecorView()
    .setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
                           | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION);
```

to hide navigation bar along with status bar

Answer (score 0):

Change the theme of your activity to not have action bar.  Best is to inherit from action bar Sherlock activity and remove the action bar

Comment: The problem is that this would hide the action bar permanently. I don't know about the OP, but in my case, I'm looking for a way to hide the action bar temporarily, and then show it again manually when a certain condition is met (not just on any user interaction, as it currently works)

Answer (score 0):

Though its too late to post an answer, but as far as I can understand the question and since I am working using the Full Screen Activity template provided in `Android Studio`, I think the answer to this question is to disable action bar which becomes visible when the user interacts with the UI, which can be achieved just by disabling the `OnClickListener` on `contentView`
i.e.

```
contentView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (TOGGLE_ON_CLICK) {
            mSystemUiHider.toggle();
        } else {
            mSystemUiHider.show();
        }
    }
});
```

i.e. comment out the `onClick` method implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Just comment out

```
if (TOGGLE_ON_CLICK) {
                    mSystemUiHider.toggle();
                } else {
                    mSystemUiHider.show();
                }
```

By default the state is Off. Toggle happens because there is a  onclick listener also added which toggles the screen.
You could simply not add it and delete the code snippet.

The newest code is
// Set up the user interaction to manually show or hide the system UI.

```
mContentView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
           // toggle();
        }
```

I simply commented out toggle() and voila